# Looking for equivalence of MIMIC-II v2.6 dataset in MIMIC-III v1.3

Tags: mimic-iii

There is a table in the MIMIC-II v2.6 database named "mimic2v26.d_codeditems" which includes a category named "type". One of the specified types is "procedure". I am looking for the equivalent data in MIMIC-III v1.3.

I am not sure but I think "mimiciii.d_icd_procedures" contains the procedure data that I am looking for. Could you please help me to identify the equivalence in MIMIC-III?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct - the category type "PROCEDURE" in the mimic2v26.d_codeditems table refers to ICD-9 procedure codes. These have been more explicitly delineated in MIMIC-III: the equivalent definitions are in D_ICD_PROCEDURES, and the actual codes for patients are in PROCEDURES_ICD.